# round to 2 decimals sh

Tags: sh, expr

I would like to get two decimals after the dot in this expression: 7/2

```
#temperature equal 7
tempeture= `cat temperature`  
rate= expr $temperature/2  
echo "$rate"
```

I'm getting 3 and I want 3.50. thks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to round to two decimails would be to use the [`bc`](http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/09/bc-command-examples-in-unix-linux.html) command and setting the `scale` variable equal to 2:

```
echo "scale=2; ($temperature/2)" | bc
```

You could also use `printf` like this:

```
printf "%.2f" $(($temperature/2))
```

Comment: You need to add the -l parameter to the bc call otherwise it will operate only with integers

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `printf`'s type specifier:

```
$ temperature=7
$ echo "$temperature/2" | bc -l
3.50000000000000000000
$ printf "%.2f\n" $(echo "$temperature/2" | bc -l)
3.50
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked and answered.
See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/179898/how-to-round-decimals-using-bc-in-bash

A bash round function:

```
round()
{
echo $(printf %.$2f $(echo "scale=$2;(((10^$2)*$1)+0.5)/(10^$2)" | bc))
};
```